# Adding sub modules to python path

Tags: python, python-import, pythonpath

I have a flask application and the root package is 'app'.
Inside that I have loads of high level modules.

Inside every script my imports need to be app.auth, app.models....
This means every module has a dependency on the root module.

How can I correct this so I can import **models.whatever**?

In `app/__init__.py` I tried:

```
import app.models
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(app.models.__file__))
print(sys.path)
```

This does add the full path, but I still get:

```
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

Comment: From "The Zen of Python" (aka `import this`): "Explicit is better than implicit."  IMHO, this isn't that ugly, and nicely explicit.

Comment: have you tried `import app.models` ?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using app. I want submodules to be able to import models... Without app